# Changing the background colors

Tags: javascript, background-color

I want to change the backgroud colors of my web page, going throw all of them. Don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
var a=0;
var b=0;
var c=0;



do{
        do{
                do{

                    c = c + 1;
                    document.body.bgcolor = "a,b,c";
                }while (c < 255);
            b = b + 1;
            document.body.bgcolor = "a,b,c";
        }while(b < 255);
    a = a + 1;
    document.body.bgcolor = "a,b,c";
}while (a < 255);
```

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?

Comment: @Jongware I think that knowing it's wrong is just about the only thing the OP got right.

Comment: Even if you  were to update the background color 100 times per second, it will take about 2 days to cycle through all of the colors.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
document.body.bgcolor = "a,b,c";
```

has three primary issues:

1. It's assigning the string `"a,b,c"`, not a string based on the *variables* `a`, `b`, and `c`.
2. The property you want to assign to is either `document.body.style.backgroundColor` or (and this is old legacy stuff) `document.body.bgColor` (note the capital `C`).
3. Numeric color values in CSS have to start with `#` to differentiate them from color names.

You need to convert `a`, `b`, and `c` to hex (hint: `a.toString(16)`, but you'll need to add a leading `0` for values < 16), and then assign them to `backgroundColor` with a `#` in front.

---

**However**, note that the browser almost certainly won't update the page display until the JavaScript code stops running. Since your code doesn't stop until the end of the series of nested loops, you won't see intermediate results. Consider using `setTimeout`.

Comment: document.body.bgColor (capital 'c') will also change the background color, harking back to the pre-css days when we did `<body bgcolor="red">`

Comment: @Pointy: LOL, was just doing that :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Great answer !